# Uploadify pass data on upload action

Tags: javascript, variables, uploadify

I really need someones help with this. Here is my uploadify code:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'swf' : 'assets/js/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
    'method' : 'post',
    'auto' : false,
    'multi' : false,
    'uploadLimit' : 1,
    'buttonText' : 'Select Image',
    'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
        var $recordId = [PASSED RECORD ID HERE];
        $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {'recordId' : $recordId});
    }
});
```

what I'm trying to do is run this when a button is clicked instead of auto uploading the file. I have a function like below that is called when the button is click.

```
function updateRecord() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
}
```

This all works fine but what i need to do is when the updateRecord function is run I need to pass the $recordId through to the upload formData.

Can some please tell me how I can pass the formData from my updateRecord function?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it, i was able to update the settings before calling the upload method:

```
function updateRecord() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {'recordId' : data});
    $('#file_upload').uploadify('upload');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, which is a working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploadify_sel = $('#uploadify');
function submitUploadify(){

    var title = $('#form_name').val();
    var main = $('#main1').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    uploadify_sel.uploadifySettings(
        'scriptData', {
            cookieID: '0daf9d4f8a44fcdc9c2aabc46c831203',
            type: 'investments',
            investment_id: '31',
            title: title,
            main: main
        }
    );
    uploadify_sel.uploadifyUpload();
}
var error = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    uploadify_sel.uploadify({
        uploader : 'http://localhost:8080/project/assets/flash/admin/uploadify.swf',
        script : 'http://localhost:8080/project/ldmadmin/investments_gallery_ajax',
        cancelImg : 'http://localhost:8080/project/assets/gfx/admin/cancel.png',
        wmode : 'transparent',
        method : 'post',
        multi : true,
        removeCompleted : false,
        folder : 'uploads',
        auto : false,
        fileDataName: 'uploadify',
        fileDesc : 'Images (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif)',
        fileExt : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif',
        buttonText: 'Choose Image File',
        scriptData : {},
        onError : function(a, b, c, d){
                                        },
        onComplete : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data){
                                        },
        onAllComplete : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data){
            if(error == null){
                window.location = window.location;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the submit button calls the function submitUploadify() as:

```
<button name="btn" class="btn" onclick="submitUploadify(); return false;">Submit form</button>
```

Just take code snippets out of it to make yours working.
This was done using Uploadify v2.1.4